# GUI appears outside eclipse gui

Tags: java, eclipse

when i put JOptionPane.showMessageDialog inside of an else if statement, the box appears outside eclipse window(behind eclipse window, have to minimize to see the ui box) and not on top of the ide, any ideas why this is happening?

this is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter measurements:  ");
        Double c = scanner.nextDouble();
        if (c>=300) {
            System.out.print("measurement exceeds available length");
        }
        else if (c<300 && c>260) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "value valid, proceed?");
        }
        else if(c<=260){
            System.out.println("measurement too short.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("enter a number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change null in `showMessageDialog(null` to its parent Component

Comment: @ScaryWombat there is no parent component since the code is a console application - which shows that it is not a good idea to use `JOptionPane` in a console application.

Comment: @Abra, This is some basic code running in an IDE, Indeed - why not just print out the error message?  If OP wants to make a proper GUI application, then OP should do it properly

Comment: im quite new to java, so what changes should i make fr the gui box to appear on top of IDE?